# Facebook button not loading in chrome

Tags: php, facebook, google-chrome, heroku

facebook button not display am getting an text only in chrome but it works in firefox.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button scope="email,user_about_me,user_interests,user_location,publish_stream" width="width_value"  size="large">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Am jus getting text "Login with Facebbok"

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>   
<script>
 // Initiate FB Object
 FB.init({
   appId: '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>', 
   status: true,
   cookie: true, 
   xfbml: true
   });
 // Reloading after successfull login
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { 
 window.location.reload(); 
 });
</script>
```

[image: Chrome output]

[image: Firefox Output]

Comment: Check Developer Tools in Chrome for errors.

Comment: not in my chrome alone .. for every chrome users ..

Comment: Okay, though could you check for errors? :S Which Chrome version? Which operating system? Is the code above all there is to it? Where is a fully working simple demo of the error? :S

Answer (score 1):

Change the Facebook SDK script src to be scheme-relative, ie without the `http:`

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

This failed initially because Chrome will block scripts transferred via HTTP when HTTPS is used, which is by default when you go to view your app in Facebook. Firefox on the other hand isn't as fussy.